# How to put keys in array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am scrapping details from a certain website. Then I want to parse HTML into a PHP array.

I want to display the array like this. I need to add key so that I can determine easily what data I want to use in the future.

```
[info] => Array
    (
        [0] => info1
        [1] => info2
    )
```

Here is my code:

```
$hk = array('info');
foreach($html->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p') as $home) {
    $hometps[] = $home->plaintext;
}
print_r(array_fill_keys($hk,$hometps));
```

But output will show me this:

```
Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [0] => info1
            [1] => info2
        )    
)
```

Comment: I think you may be confused about how arrays look when they are printed to screen.  Would you rather have a variable called `info` and it just be a 1-dimensional / indexed array?  Perhaps you could clarify your desired output array structure by adding some more input data / levels.

Answer (score 0):

I think everybody is confused about the issue and question here. The following will give you an array named `$info`, which will hold the returned values of the foreach loop:

```
$info = Array();
foreach($html->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p') as $home) {
    array_push($info,$home->plaintext);
}
print_r($info);
```

This will output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => info1 
    [1] => info2 
)
```

Hope this was what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: $hk = array('info');
$hometps = Array();
foreach($html->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p') as $home) {
    $hometps[] = $home->plaintext;
}
print_r(array_fill_keys($hk,$hometps));

I did it like this, still giving me same unwanted output

Comment: See if this rocks your boat.

Answer (score 0):

Array element cannot stand on its own. Considering you want `info` as an index, it has to be a part of an array. 
If you want the list of info available then assign them to `$info` variable and when you print_r($info), like this:

```
$info = array();
foreach($html->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p') as $home) {
    $info[] = $home->plaintext;
}
print_r($info);
```

And you will get:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => info1
        [1] => info2
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be trying to rename the representation value in the array also known as the 'key' I guess. I recommend doing that directly to the output of the html while going into the foreach. That should solve your issue. It would look something like this(original example at bottom):

```
$hk = array('info');
foreach($html->find('div[id="home"] div[id="topinfo"] p') as $hk => $home) {
$hometps[] = $home->plaintext;
}
print_r($hometps);


foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on each iteration.

[PHP.net:foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)